# In opencv how do I get a list of segemented regions

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision

I'm working on a project where I want to evaluate certain parameters on regions of a segemented image. So I have the following code

```
  col = cv2.imread("in.jpg",1)
  col=cv2.resize(col,(width,height),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
  res=cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(col,20,45,3)
```

and would now like to somehow get a list of masks per region in res. 
So for example if res was now something like this

```
1 1 0 2 1 
1 0 0 2 1
0 0 2 2 1
```

I would like to get an output such as

```
1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
,
0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
,
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 0
,
0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1
```

So that is a mask for each group of the same values that are connected. Maybe this could somehow involve the floodfill function? I can 
see that maybe by looping over every pixel and then flood filling and comparing to see if that set of pixels was already set might work but that seems like a very expensive way so is there something faster?
Oh and here is an example image of res after the code has run 
[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with [`cv2.connectedComponents`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents) -

```
def list_seg_regs(a): # a is array
    out = []
    for i in np.unique(a):
        ret, l = cv2.connectedComponents((a==i).astype(np.uint8))
        for j in range(1,ret):
            out.append((l==j).astype(int)) #skip .astype(int) for bool
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [53]: a = np.array([
    ...:    [1, 1, 0, 2, 1],
    ...:    [1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
    ...:    [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]])

In [54]: out = list_seg_regs(a)

In [55]: out[0]
Out[55]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

In [56]: out[1]
Out[56]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [57]: out[2]
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

In [58]: out[3]
Out[58]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: @Thijser So, OpenCV2 doesn't have `cv2.connectedComponents`?

Comment: `Scipy` seems to have a counterpart - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html

Comment: @Thijser Well the question had `a` as a 2D array, but I think you are working with a RGB image, so its 3D array? To find out, do `image.ndim`, where `image` would be your input image.

Comment: Yhea you are correct I put it in a grayscale image and that works, the new issue is that it randomly get's killed (no message just 'killed')

Comment: Alright it's running out of memory (all 31 gigs of it), do you know of a way of doing this that uses less memory for say my example image?

Comment: @Thijser Hmm, so let me ask you to get the bigger picture - How do you intend to use the output?

Comment: I want to use each mask to calculate a given set of values (neural error, average colour, difference between two images ext.) for the values underneath the mask. So that means that perhaps I shouldn't first store the results and then use them but rather use them when I generate them.

Comment: @Thijser Exactly! You have your answer there :)